# Objective-C: limit scope of variable to class

Tags: objective-c, scope

**Problem:** I'll like to define a variable, which **scope is the class** it is defined in. Neither only one method of the class, nor a true global variable.

**Idee:** I tried to define the variable in the implementation block of the class, but outside of any method. Like this:

```
@implementation DBManager
BOOL const gCommentsOnOff = YES; // to switch-on the comments in all methods
...
@end
```

I thought, the variable would be private to the class. However, if I use the same definition in a second class, I obtain the following compiler error:

```
duplicate symbol _gCommentsOnOff in:
    ...
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Obviously, the variable is not private to the class.

Question: How can I define a boolean variable (with the value YES) + the scope is limited to the class?

Comment: Do you need a constant or a variable? I'm asking this because if you need a constant, other answers will work just fine, since a constant can be safely shared between class instances. Otherwise you can't use static variables. You should use instance variables or properties instead. Preferably properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't limit the scope to class-level in Objective-C, instead you have to declare a global variable, as you have done, but limit its scope to the implementation file (`.m`) using `static`.  This will do what you want, provided no other classes are defined within this implementation file (they normally aren't).

Also putting the declaration inside the `@implementation` section has no effect.

```
static const BOOL gCommentsOnOff = YES; 

@implementation DBManager
...
@end
```

Comment: In your answer you said that putting in inside `@implementation` has no effect. Could you please explain why? There was couple of time when I was declaring _static_ var inside class implementation and it was behaving the way I expected. Does it mean it was re-initialized per each class instance?

Comment: @gontovnik No it has no effect, although it does not hurt either.  It's a C declaration and nothing to do with the class declaration.

Comment: Thank you very much. Both of you.

Comment: @trojanfoe: This was exactly the solution I was hoping for. I like to collect variables, which are used to check/test the program, at the top of the file.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you want to define static variable in your class, not within the whole project. If yes, then you can declare variable like this in your *.m* file just before `@implementation`:

```
static const BOOL gCommentsOnOff = YES;
```

Currently it complains in your app because you, probably, declared static/extern variable in different class *.h* file with the same name.

If you want to declare instance variable, then you can do like this:

```
@implementation DGManager {
    BOOL gCommentsOnOff;
}

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        gCommentsOnOff = YES;
    }
}
```